# Execution process of goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:4.0-rc1:process failed

Tags: java, maven, version, conflict

I have a problem which I want to share and probably find your assistance.

Just today I reinstall my Dev environment and realized that can't build my project using maven (version 3.6.3, but I've tried older as well). The issue stack trace is next:

```
Execution process of goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:4.0-rc1:process failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'process' in the plugin 'org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:4.0-rc1' due to an API incompatibility: 
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: 
org/bsc/maven/plugin/processor/MainAnnotationProcessorMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

The Java version is : `Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre`

I've spent some time to understand what is wrong and why on the local machine it works but on the new DEV machine - doesn't. I know that problem is that the dependency of maven plugin (maven-processor-plugin) is built by a newer version than I use for a project. But WHY Maven loads this release candidate version instead of stable 3.3.3?

Then I removed `~/.m2/repository/org/bsc/maven/maven-processor-plugin` from my local machine and... yes, I reached the same issue as I have on my Dev machine. My local Maven version is 3.6.1

I assume that Maven starts using the latest version of that plugin and moves forward without backward compatibility. It sounds like a last Java 8 days in the Maven eco-system, but I won't believe in that.

BTW: `MAVEN PROCESSOR PLUGIN » 4.0-rc1` was released (Apr 17, 2020), this explains why previously I didn't have such an issue.

If someone has a similar issue or can explain what's going on with Maven - I will be so thankful. Thank you all in advance, stay safe!

P.S. How the plugin configuration looks like in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>src/generated</outputDirectory>
            <processors>
              <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
            </processors>
            <compilerArguments>-ApersistenceXml="src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence-data.xml"</compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

P.P.S. I'm not blocked by this, because I just used a Version tag and set the latest stable version of the plugin `3.3.3`. But I'm still curious why such conflict happens. And, again, I will be so happy for any ideas and comments.